# how to send the dateFormat to api from formik datePicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, formik

I want to send my date format as dd-MM-yyyy to the api, I can get it to show the right format on the client side but when I send it to the api I receive something like yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss and so on, but I only want the date.

This is what I have:

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
export class AdminPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      initialValues: {
        dato: new Date()

      }
    };
  }
handleChange = date => {
        this.setState({
          dato: date
        });
      };
render(){
    let {initialValues} = this.state;
      return(
        <div>
          <h1 className="signupheader">Arbejds seddel</h1>
        <div>
          <Formik
              initialValues={initialValues}
              validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                dato: Yup.string().min(3, 'der skal flere tal på').required('husk at udfylde dato')
            })}
              onSubmit={(values, { setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
                setStatus();
                fetch('https://nameless-ocean-57332.herokuapp.com/arbejdsseddel', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    body: JSON.stringify(values)
                })
                .then((response) => (response.json()))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
              }}


            >
            {({ values }) => {
            return(
               <Form>
                <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="dato">
                    Dato<span className="req">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <DatePicker className='form-control' 
                    selected={this.state.dato}
                    onChange={dato => this.handleChange(dato)}
                    value={Selection}
                    dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
                    withPortal
                    disabledKeyboardNavigation
                  />
                  </div>
                   <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={isSubmitting}>Send som E-mail</button>
                                {isSubmitting &&
                                    <img alt="" src="data:image/gif" />
                                }
                            </div>
                            {status &&
                                <div className={'alert alert-danger'}>{status}</div>
                            }
                              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Print</button>
                      </div>
                </Form>
                )
                }}
         </Formik>
         );
      }
}
```

So I just want the api to receive my custom format and not the iso format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to modify your `onSubmit` function:

```
onSubmit={(values, { setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
  const yourDate = values.dato;
  const yourFormattedDate =
    yourDate.getDate() +
    "-" +
    (yourDate.getMonth() + 1) +
    "-" +
    yourDate.getFullYear();
  const updatedValues = { ...values, dato: yourFormattedDate }
  setStatus();
  fetch("https://nameless-ocean-57332.herokuapp.com/arbejdsseddel", {
    method: "post",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(updatedValues)
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}}
```

Before sending it to the API you reformat it in the desired way. A more elegant way of course would be when your Datepicker component would return the string but you did not provide any information about it.

Sometimes it is hard to avoid to do some manual reformatting of the form data before sending it to a backend when an API for example requires some strange format. Here it is a good way to do this in the `onSubmit` function.

Comment: The DatePicker Component is a npm package that's why I didn't provide any info about it.
in the body you only send the date, but I also need to send Email with it and an array

Comment: I updated my answer. Now everything that is in `values` will be included in the API call. Could you provide an import of the Datepicker in your question? Otherwise it is just possible to guess which one you acutally use from npm.

Comment: Thanks it's working now :-). I have added the import